# Dynamically search for Facebook pages on my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, search-box

I would like to have a search box on my site that works like the Facebook search box, but searching only for Pages.

I know that using the Graph API I can do searches like these:

```
search?q=London&type=page
```

and it will return a list of pages related to the keyword "London".

The difference is that I would like it to be dynamic. So that when the user starts typing "Lon" it starts suggesting pages. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the most straightforward is that you just call the API as the user types

```
search?q=L&type=page
search?q=Lo&type=page
search?q=Lon&type=page
search?q=Lond&type=page
search?q=Londo&type=page
search?q=London&type=page
```

And update your app view after each API call.